# php7.3 doesn't appear on /run/php/

Tags: php, nginx, joomla

I have a Joomla server with NGINX and I've just upgraded my php version from php7.0 to 7.3, but I can't use the new version.

The problem is that in `/run/php/` (and `/var/run/php/`) I can only find `php7.0-fpm.pid` and `php7.0-fpm.sock`, but the 7.3 version does not appear, so if I update my site nginx config to:

```
...
location ~ \.php$ {
            # fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }
...
```

I get a 502 bad gateway when entering my site.

Why php7.3 hasn't started? How do I switch to 7.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-FPM is a system service, just like Nginx is. Look up the standard "service management" operations for your distro (I'm assuming Debian or similar):

- Display status: `systemctl status php7.3-fpm`
- Start manually now: `systemctl start php7.3-fpm`
- Auto-start after reboot: `systemctl enable php7.3-fpm`

Comment: Okay, solved it. Tried to start it manually but got "service not found", so I `apt install php7.3-fpm` to ensure it was correcly installed and everything is working now. Thanks for the help! It lead me to the solution!

Comment: You didn't even have it _installed_? :(